# Why can I still modify my Code Signed Electron app?

Tags: macos, code-signing

We developed a macOS app with Electron. We code-signed and notarized it using Electron-Forge, which generated an `*.app` package, inside a `Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources` file with an entry for each of our *.js files, such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>files</key>
    <dict>
    [...]
        <key>Resources/app/dist/backend/electron/app-helium/src/index.js</key>
        <data>
        EI+Z6X/tOHL8zzCXFQSHCBz0JCs=
        </data>
[...]
```

I was very surprised that I can still modify the contents of the `index.js` file (e.g. add a message box which is shown when the app starts) inside the "App" package. When I start the application, macOS (Big Sur) doesn't complain, and happily displays the added message box.

Isn't that what code signing is all about - not being able to alter the contents?

Comment: This is a pretty deep problem, since code signing is geared to compiled binaries more than interpreted languages and when code can alter itself, things get weird. My hunch is you’re signing the wrapper in essence here.

Comment: @bmike but the file list in `CodeResources` includes all *.js files as well. Shouldn`t these be protected against changes this way?

Comment: Can you upload a small sample to GitHub - it’s hard for me to grok the details without seeing the details. Would be curious what the code sign syntax is in addition to the very nice snippet of the xml you already provided. You likely are assuming the first check isn’t as sticky as you had hoped - https://eclecticlight.co/2018/12/22/how-thoroughly-does-gatekeeper-check-existing-apps/

Comment: Sorry I can't currently upload anything to github due to company restrictions. But it's easy to create a sample. Just create a standard electron app using https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-template. Then build the *.dmg as described in https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/tutorial/code-signing#electron-forge, using your Apple developer credentials (you'll need an application-specific password). Then, in the resulting app package, change the html in `Contents/Resources/app/src/index.html`. You can run this app without any problem, and the changed html will show up.

Comment: I found another way to reproduce the described behavior.
Since VS Code is an electron app, you can install VS Code and change any file. E.g. i added `const foo = 1;` to the file `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/main.js`. After this change I would expect that MacOS complains about an invalid signature. But I'm able to open and use VS Code like before.

Comment: I don't believe macOS really cares about modifications within the Resources directory (my guess is that it might not check the code signature of those files after the first run). I guess that's just a "funny" quirk of using a glorified web browser as an "app".

Comment: I added a bug to the electron forge issue tracker: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/2798